# Share internet between iPad and PC

Tags: ipad, internet-sharing, pc

I've been searching for this for a while without satisfactory results.

One way to share internet from the PC to the iPad is by doing an ad-hoc network, if the PC allow us to do so. Otherwise, I have two questions:

- If the PC is connected to internet, How can we share internet from the PC to the iPad via USB?
- Suppose the iPad is connected to internet by means of some wireless network, How can we share internet from the iPad to the PC via USB?

I have an iPad Version: 5.1.1 (9B206), Model: MB292LL (the first ones).

Alternatively, if the iPad is connected to some wireless network, is it possible make it an access point, so it extends the range of the network?

Comment: If the iPad is connected to a wireless network ... can't you connect the PC to the same network?  Alternatively, if the PC is connected to a wired network you could conceivably make it into a wireless access point and connect the iPad to that. Either would require a WiFi adapter on the PC -- but last time I checked, you could get a USB WiFi adapter starting at around USD 20.

Comment: @David Indeed, I've got one USB WiFi adapter. And a new computer a as well :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK iDevices MUST use Wifi for internet accesss. So No USB.

iDevices can provide an internet connection only when Personal Hotspot is enabled (So it's only for Cellular iDevices). In this only case you can use USB for internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

good question using a serial bus controller or USB holder to USB holder plug and a lightning connector and a ordinary LAN modem is required for accessing wifi connection with ethernet cables.